# Multi master replication in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Wanted to analyze the Migration path from CockroachDB to YugaByteDB.
Does Yugabyte support multiregion cluster out of the box with master-master replication?
Let’s say we have

Region 1:
WEB + API + DB1

Region 2:
WEB + API + DB2

DB1 should be eventually consistent to DB2. While we keep the latencies low.

The same configuration in CockroachDB causes Region1 OR Region2 to have high latencies, due to the round-trip of data during the replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is supported with https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/deploy/multi-dc/async-replication/.

But note that they're 2 separate clusters.
So in production, you'll have a minimum of 2 clusters of 3 nodes each (assuming 3 RF).